# Burninate "lines" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[lines](/questions/tagged/lines) on SO is another one of those useless tags that is used to mean many things and thus means nothing. Drawing lines? Lines of code? Lines of output? Geometry? The [lines](/questions/tagged/lines) tag's got you covered.

Kill it with fire.

Comment: Yup - that is a pretty darn useless tag ;)